# How to use Yii2 schema builder for a migration?

Tags: php, yii2, database-migration

According to the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-migrations.html#creating-migrations)

I can use the code below to create a migration that creates a new table.
Just wondering what I am missing to use this new feature? By new feature I mean from this line in the documentation.

Many Thanks!

"Since 2.0.5 schema builder which provides more convenient way defining column schema was introduced so migration above could be written like the following:"

```
use yii\db\Schema;
use yii\db\Migration;

class m150101_185401_create_news_table extends \yii\db\Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        $this->createTable('news', [
            'id' => Schema::primaryKey(),
            'title' => Schema::string()->notNull(),
            'content' => Schema::text(),
        ]);
    }

    public function down()
    {
        $this->dropTable('news');
    }
}
```

But when I try I get an error message.

```
Yii Migration Tool (based on Yii v2.0.5)

Total 1 new migration to be applied:
    m150717_020723_create_news_table

Apply the above migration? (yes|no) [no]:yes
*** applying m150717_020723_create_news_table
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method yii\db\Schema::primaryKey() in
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Check your `composer.json` for containing valid Yii2 version, for example:

```
"yiisoft/yii2": ">=2.0.6",
```

Also check used application type, see [this issue](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/issues/51) and samdark's answer:

> Current advanced is using new migrations style which will be available
>   in 2.0.6 only. Basic does not.

**2)** Simply update framework to the latest version by running:

```
composer update
```

Comment: I thought the latest stable version was 2.0.5 though and according to that documentation it was new in 2.0.5. Mind you the official change log does not suggest it came in then. It was just a security fix.
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.5/framework/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: No not yet.
Got an error message.
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Is 2.0.6 not stable? I also have this in composer.json?
"minimum-stability": "stable",

Comment: @johnsnails Added note about used application type.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I got it working. I installed Yii using this:
composer create-project --prefer-dist --stability=dev yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced yii-application
NB the --stability=dev which is not in the advanced guide default choice.

That automatically added this to my composer.json
"yiisoft/yii2": ">=2.0.6",
Not sure if I need to mention that in your answer.